# keys values in array like array[0] and so on

Tags: iphone

I am using this code

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary;

NSArray * yourKeys;
yourKeys = [yourDictionary allValues];
```

to get the value of dictionary. But i want that  array output in this form : array[0] ,array[1] while I am getting the output in console as below:-

```
2013-01-12 18:44:10.213 Birthday_Reminder[2871:c07] (
{
},
"Arpit Sihare")
```

and so on values.
so plz help me to get those values in this form and also I'm using KABPersonfirstnameproperty to retrieve those name from address book.

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    NSArray *thePeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSMutableArray* allPeoplesDicts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id person in thePeople)
    {
        ABMultiValueRef phone =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
       // NSMutableArray* phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *phones=[[NSDictionary alloc]init ];
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++)
        {
            NSString *phone = [(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones,i) autorelease];
            [phones addObject:phone];
        }
        NSDictionary* personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"Name",phones,@"PhoneNumbers",nil];
        [phones release];


        NSArray * yourKeys;
        yourKeys = [personDict allValues];


        NSLog(@"%@",yourKeys);
        [allPeoplesDicts addObject:personDict];
        [personDict release];
    }
```

and I want firstname in array form that when i use nslog(@"%@",array[0]) it should print value stored in array first place and soon like array[1]....

Comment: Please explain more on what your problem is.

Comment: Please edit your question with the new code, rather than posting a comment - it will make formatting much prettier.

Comment: and I want firstname in array form that when i use nslog(@"%@",array[0]) it should print value stored in array first place and soon like array[1]....

Comment: You asked for the values.  Those are the values -- an empty NSDictionary and an NSString.  Did you want the keys instead, as implied by the variable name?

Comment: Why do you iterate on the empty phones dictionary?

Comment: Note that `allValues` will not return dictionary values in any defined order -- the order will essentially be random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too hard to understand what you are trying to say. I tried and found...

If you just want to store all the `firstName` (which is your key I think) then just make `yourKeys` an `NSMutableArray` and add the `names` to that Array. :

```
[yourKeys addObject:names];
```

Simple !!